# Singleton scenario, overloading getInstance with different parameters?

Tags: c++, design-patterns, singleton

I have a singleton class for the settings of the software. In different places in the large software it is possible to getInstance and use it to access settings which are already read into the settings class from a file. However:

- In initial call it is necessary to pass a "model name" (the software loads and runs simulation models) and based on the name, the software will load settings of the selected model.

  Settings::getInstance("building1")
- In later calls, it is not desired (or sometimes possible) to pass "model name" again. So it will be ideal if we can call without the model name.

What should I do in this scenario? Have 2 getInstance methods? Or set the "model name" to an static variable in Settings class before making the first call to getInstance? Or what?

Comment: Use a Singleton -> no sympathy.

Comment: Perhaps just don't use a singleton?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Having 2 `getInstance()` methods sounds like a recipe for disaster :) I would imagine the users of the class would always be asking: "Well which one do I use?" What would happen if someone called the wrong version first?

Instead of using 2 `getInstance()` methods, I think it would be better to use the static variable approach, and set it early in the initialization phase. But this is also error-prone.

Even better would be to consider some sort of a factory that takes the model name upon instantiation and has a singleton internally. The factory could be something like this:

```
class SettingsFactory
{
public:
    SettingsFactory(const std::string &modelName);
    Settings *getUniqueSettingsInstance();

private:
    SettingsFactory(); // cant instantiate the default ctor

    // put the singleton stuff here
};
```

Comment: @SteveTownsend, Ya, I agree, I reworded the answer a bit.

Comment: I also like the factory approach. Let me think and see how should I cleanly implement it.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not one to say singletons are evil, but here you really shouldn't be using them. A general rule of thumb: if your class has some state that is in any way perceivable from the outside, it should not be a singleton. Global state should be avoided for widely known reasons.

Your class clearly has state because it requires some initialization. Do not make it a singleton. Find some other way to structure your code.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, why don't you just overload the getInstance() method with a default value of `NULL`?  When you call your getInstance a second time, it shouldn't matter if the model name is a `NULL char*` because you don't need it to construct your object this time.

```
class Settings
{
   // ..
   static Settings * getInstance(char * modelName = NULL);
}
```

Comment: Nice idea, but what happens if its already been instantiated and someone passes in the modelName? They would expect something to happend, but most likely it wont.

Comment: @Brady - I'd be tempted to put in an assert for that scenario, I'm  actually of the view that the OP shouldn't be using a singleton at all but I think this would work on the whole.

Comment: @Benj - What is an alternate method to access settings from different parts of a large program (and avoid reading settings file every time, since I refer to settings millions of times per second in different parts of the software).

Comment: @Benj, just today, Ive started seeing the acronym "OP", what is that? As for the assert, that would work, but I could just imagine my Chief Architect seeing that and getting heartburn :) and saying something like, if its going to cause an assert, then why's it there...

Comment: @Brady - OP = Original Poster

Comment: @wmac Pass a pointer/shared_ptr to the settings in the constructor of other key classes which store it as a member.. It's usually surprising how few classes need a pointer to something like this before you can access it from everywhere.